# Proof of an identity concerning the prime $\zeta$ function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, mobius-inversion, euler-product, dirichlet-convolution

I have to prove the following identity:
let $P(s)=\sum_p\frac{1}{p^s}$, for $Re(s)>1$, then
\begin{equation}
P(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log(\zeta(ns)).
\end{equation}
I proved that
\begin{equation}
\log(\zeta(s))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{P(ns)}{n}.
\end{equation}
I know I have to use Möbius inversion formula to deduce the result from this identity, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 2):

A more general form of Möbius inversion is the following:
[$$g(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(ns)}n \iff f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)\,\frac{g(ns)}{n},$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations)
which is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you, do you know where I can find a proof of this theorem?